# How to collect multiple named ES6 exports in one named export?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using code from the official documentation. You can find it [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-slice-state-and-action-types)

This is the relevant line:

```
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions
```

I want to export all the slice reducers without explicitly having to type their names. I want to do this because as the number of reducers increases it becomes cumbersome to maintain the export statement updated to reflect all the CRUD operations I might do on the slice reducers.

Comment: `export counterSlice.actions` gives me an error  `parsing error: Declaration or statement expected`

Comment: How about `export {...counterSlice.actions}`?

Comment: I get another error message: `Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'counterSlice'.`

Comment: Only way is `export const actions = todoSlice.actions`. And import it as `import { actions } from 'your-file'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/6546440/rashomon

```
export const actions = todoSlice.actions;
// import it as:
import { actions } from 'your-file';
```